# Python SciPy Module Error Message

Tags: python, scipy

What am I doing wrong here?  Below is the code and here is the error I'm getting:

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'chi2_contingency'

The fisher test works just fine and prints the oddsration and p value but the chi2 test is not.  Done some looking around here and changed the way I was importing packages/modules but no luck.  Any help appreciated.  Probably something simple I'm missing.  Thanks in advance.

```
import sys
import numpy as np
import scipy
from scipy import stats

oddsratio, pvalue = scipy.stats.fisher_exact([[56, 891], [48, 12873]])

print oddsratio
print pvalue

obs = np.array([[56, 891], [48, 12873]])

print obs

g, p, dof, expctd = scipy.stats.chi2_contingency(obs, correction=True)

print p
```

Comment: Why not `stats.fisher_exact(...)` and `stats.chi2_contingency(...)`; after all, you're first doing `from scipy import stats`, so no logic in prepending `scipy` in front of `stats` later.

Comment: What Python version and what Scipy version are you using?

Comment: Works fine for me, using python 2.7.9 and scipy 0.15.1.  `chi2_contingency` was added to scipy later than `fisher_exact`.  Check the scipy version that you are using.

Comment: To check the scipy version, run: `import scipy; print scipy.__version__`

Comment: Turns out it was a version issue - updated to 0.15.1 and it works fine now.  Sorry for the newb question but thanks for the accurate answers.

Answer (score 1):

While this looks like a quirk, it's a side-effect of the layout of `scipy` being a package containing a module `stats`. Try:

```
import scipy.stats

g, p, dof, e = scipy.stats.chi2_contingency([[56, 891], [48, 12873]], correction=True)
print p  # 1.4896896046343034e-79
```

Comment: The fact that `fisher_test` works is weird. Are you running this in an IPython notebook? There could be some non-obvious hidden state there.